# Long click listener not working on child views of viewgroup

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout

I have some child views in my Main Layout , I need that if I long press on main Layout then it will call onLongpress from anywhere in layout . But it is not working if i long press on child view .

Like in my demo , i need have a relaytivelayout in which i have button and i have applied longclicklistener on relativelayout and applied onCLicklistener on button
Now longclick is working everywhere inside that relativelayout accept that button area

I want that longclick need to work on button area also , And i don't want to call btn.performlongclick()

Here is my code , can someone help me

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/mainLayout"
    android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_dark"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">
    
    
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="70dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:backgroundTint="#00bcd4"
        android:text="Button click"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:textSize="25sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />
        
    </RelativeLayout>






import android.os.Bundle
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.view.View
import android.widget.Button
import android.widget.Toast

public class DemoActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    lateinit var mainLayout: View
    lateinit var btn: Button;

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_demo)
        mainLayout=findViewById(R.id.mainLayout)
        btn=findViewById(R.id.btn)
        mainLayout.setOnLongClickListener(View.OnLongClickListener {
            Toast.makeText(applicationContext, "Long Pressed".toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            return@OnLongClickListener false

        })
        btn.setOnClickListener(View.OnClickListener {
            Toast.makeText(applicationContext, "btn Pressed".toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        })
    }
}
```

Comment: Is there a reason why you dont want to call btn.performlongclick()

Comment: yes because in my case i am adding views at run time from different different classes , so i need to send all required data in all views in that case

Comment: Can you try adding `android:duplicateParentState="true" in the button?

Answer (score 0):

Could you try disabling long click listener for the given button by setting the attribute on the button in the
XML: `android:longClickable="false"`

Answer (score 0):

You can set the same long click listener for both of them.

```
private val longClickListener = View.OnLongClickListener { 
    // do something when button and main layout long clicked
}

btn.setOnLongClickListener(longClickListener)
mainLayout.setOnLongClickListener(longClickListener)
btn.setOnClickListener {
    // do something when button clicked
}
```